# Returning a DialogResult from child Form referenced in parent Form project

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

In a multiple projects solution I had a startup WinForms project with 2 Forms, expecting a `DialogResult` whenever the child Form was shown to continue execution in my main Form.

```
var form2 = new ThisNameSpace.FormChild();
var dResult = form2.ShowDialog(this);

if(dResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Do some work
}
else
{
    // Do other work
}
```

For some reason, I had to move the child Form in another project. I've referenced the new Project's dll in my main startup Form project but I'm now unable to return a dialog result. When my child Form closes the `FormClosing` event of the main Form is raised with `CloseReason.None` and the application exits. How can I work this around?

Comment: What does it mean that you are unable to return a dialog result. Does `var dResult = form2.ShowDialog(this);` still compile? Or do you mean that your application crashes? How do you close your child form, OK button of Close button in the window caption?

Comment: My bad, I was forcibly closing my main Form, when `CloseReason` was `CloseReason.None` under certain circumstances by calling the `FormClosing` event with null arguments (`CloseReason.None`). I'm now raising the childs `FormClosing` event with a different close reason and cancel the `FormClosingEventArgs` in my main form. Still why does `FormClosing` raised on child form with a specific `CloseReason` raises the `FormClosing` event on the main form with `CloseReason = CloseReason.None` ?

Comment: Do you mean that you explicitly raise `FromClosing`? this is not how you should do it, you should call `Close`. You also didn't answer how the form is closed by user, OK button or close button. When you call `ShowDialog` you put up a modal dialog, and user is expected to close it. Where do you raise the event and why?

Comment: Yes, I'm now calling `FormClosing` with `CloseReason = None` when the OK button is pressed on the child Form and setting the form's `DialogResult` to OK. If the user clicks on the Close button (`CloseReason = UserClosing`) I'm setting the Form's `DialogResult` to `Cancel`.

Comment: You are doing it wrong, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You should not raise `FormClosing` event yourself, and you should not write any custom code to just close the dialog.

Instead do this:

- on your OK button in child form, set `DialogResult` property to `OK`
- on your child form, set set `Accept Button` property to point to your OK button

that's all you need to close the window and correct DialogResult will be returned.

If you ever need to close it 'manually' (and this is rare for modal dialogs, i.e. those opened with `ShowDialog` instead of `Show`), use `Close` method.

Comment: Why not? 

On my main Form, for example, I'm minimizing the Form on the tray when the close button is pressed or on Ctrl+F4, ie when the CloseReason is UserClosing. Under some circumstances though, I want to forcibly close the application, and calling just this.Close() won't close it, it will just minimize it on the tray. So I need to raise the event programmatically with a different close reason.

Comment: The event is raised as a part of more complex workflow, so it is not enough to just raise it. In other words, the event is a consequence of closing, not the trigger of closing. You obviously work around normal closing procedure to implement 'minimize to tray' functionality, so it doesn't work as designed. If you just want to close the app, call `Application.Exit();`

Comment: Thats what I'm doing... If the user wants to close the app, I'm calling Application.Exit(). But when I want to forcibly close the  app, I need to provide a different close reason, do some database work and then exit. For the moment I set the CloseReason on the latter occasion to MdiFormClosing but I'm not quite sure what this close reason is. None, UserClosing, ApplicationExitCall, and WindowsShutDown are already used for different occasions.

Comment: I still don't get how forcible closing differs from normal closing in your UI.  If you just call `Close()`, you will have `UserClosing` as a reason and DialogResult whatever you set, if you use AcceptButton you will have `None` and DialogResult OK, if you use Application.Exit you will have `ApplicationExitCall` and DialogResult None, and if you click Close button you will have `UserClosing` and Cancel. 

What combination do you want to get?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make clear in my last couple posts that I was talking about the parent Form. Concerning the child Form, it's working with a workaround. I'm setting the DialogResult, DialogResult.OK on OK button click followed by a call to FormClosing with None as ClosingReason. And UserClosing when the user closes the form from the Close button. The problem is that in each occasion the Closing event propagates and raises to the Parent Form with None ClosingReason. In my parent FormClosing code, I cancel the FormClosingEventArgs when the Reason is None and the app continues with the returned

Comment: DialogResult from the child Form. Thats why I'm temporary using MdiFormClosing as CloseReason in the situation where I need to forcibly close the Parent Form.